# Drupal7 and Hiphop Missing index.php in the Urls

Tags: 7

I built and installed HipHop VM based on the steps from https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/building-and-installing-hhvm-on-ubuntu-12.04

I am running Drupal7 and Ubuntu 12.04. Everything works fine but when I click on a link in the page the resulting URL is missing index.php in it.

For example when I click on a link for adding node, the url in browser is http://10.11.x.x:9001/?q=node%2Fadd& and it is resulting in a File Not Found

Can I handle this using Drupal or is it something that I need to tweak in HHVM.

Comment: Can you enable clean URLs?

Comment: Not yet there. I am still trying to get it work without clear URLs. 

By the way the "The clean URL test failed." when I checked it now.